# Preferences between activity and service

Tags: android, android-service, android-preferences

I tried to find an explanation about this issue but I couldn't find anything.

I have a remote service that is working in the background. This service reads some preferences from a SharedPreference.

The problem I have happens when I change a preference from a PreferenceActivity (the activity and the service belong to the same application and the same package). I change the preference and it is saved correctly, but as soon as the service reads that preference (the service never modifies the preferences, it only modifies some internal preferences that cannot be modified from the PreferenceActivity) the preference is 'resetted' and the service gets the resetted value.

This is happening with CheckBoxPreference. I don't know if this would happen with other kind of preferences as I don't have any of them.

After I change the preference I should restart the service? Or I need to 'refresh' the preferences in the service? Maybe this is a problem related with using HoloEverywhere?

To get the SharedPreference object I use the following code:

```
PreferenceManager.wrap(context, getSharedPreferencesName(context), Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
```

This code is specific for HoloEverywhere and it equals this:

context.getSharedPreferences(getSharedPreferencesName(context), Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);

'getSharedPreferencesName()' just returns a string composed by "package.name_preferences".

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> I have a remote service that is working in the background.

Why did you make your service be remote?

> I change the preference and it is saved correctly, but as soon as the service reads that preference (the service never modifies the preferences, it only modifies some internal preferences that cannot be modified from the PreferenceActivity) the preference is 'resetted' and the service gets the resetted value.

That's because you made your service remote. Simply remove the `android:process` attribute from your manifest, to have all your components run in the same process, and this problem will go away. Along the way, you will make the user happier, because you won't be consuming as much RAM and battery.

> After I change the preference I should restart the service? Or I need to 'refresh' the preferences in the service?

If you truly have a legitimate reason for having a remote service -- and IMHO there's a greater chance that I will spontaneously regrow my hair -- you will need to restart the service's process, AFAIK. `SharedPreferences` are cached per process, and I don't know of a way to force Android to reload `SharedPreferences` from disk except by restarting the process.

Or, you could not have a remote service. The choice is yours.

Comment: I need to use a remote service as this service has to keep running on background listening for new camera photos to upload them automatically. Thanks for your reply.